# Which token to use for checking payment details?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

Hello I'm am trying to integrate canvas payment to a facebook app, in my payment callback I call https://graph.facebook.com/PAYMENT_ID?access_token=APP_ACCESS_TOKEN but I receive an invalid token error, in fact I don't understand which token I have to use, it's not explained at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/howtos/payments/fulfillment

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK I found a usefull page about access token: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/
I gave me my app access token, and payment now works !